# Linebreaks in pandas column names

Tags: python, pandas

Do you know how to do linebreaks inside pandas column names? I have some columns with long labels and I want to break them when I display the dataframe. Something like this doesnt seem to work.

```
pd.DataFrame({'this is \n colummn A':[1,2,3], 'this is \n colummn B':[3,4,5]})


    this is colummn A   this is colummn B
0   1                   3
1   2                   4
2   3                   5
```

Comment: This is a display issue, what does `df.columns.tolist()` show?

Comment: Thanks Ed, `df.columns.tolist()` returns

`['this is \n colummn A', 'this is \n colummn B']`

Comment: So it's a display issue, ipython/pandas is ignoring this so that the displayed output aligns neatly. Not sure how you can fix this

Comment: Well, you could do a multi-index, but that's overkill for something that is probably not a good idea to begin with...